# Django form POST resulting in 404

Tags: django, django-forms

I am attempting to take in a form for `update` or `delete`, run the process and either return the updated url, or the updated list of objects.  I've got the dynamic url building working, but when I hit `submit` I get a 404.  I am struggling with the how to process the POST, as it doesn't even seem to be hitting that far in the code.  Code below:

urls.py

```
    path("customers/", views.customers, name="customers"),
    path("customers/customer/<int:id>/", views.customer),
```

forms.py

```
    class CustomerMaintForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = AppCustomerCst
            fields = ('id_cst', 'is_active_cst', 'name_cst', 'address_1_cst', 'address_2_cst', 'address_3_cst',
                      'city_cst', 'state_cst', 'zip_cst', 'country_cst', 'salesrep_cst', 'type_cst',
                      'is_allowed_flat_cst', 'iddef_cst', 'date_created_cst', 'date_suspended_cst',
                      'date_first_tran_cst', 'date_last_tran_cst', 'is_credit_hold_cst',
                      'old_balance_cst', 'balance_notify_cst', 'balance_statement_cst',
                      'balance_conversion_cst', 'balance_cst', 'receive_emails_cst',
                      'contact_domain_cst'
                      )
            labels = {'id_cst': 'Customer ID', 'is_active_cst': 'Active?', 'name_cst': mark_safe('<p>Name'),
                      'address_1_cst': 'Address 1',
                      'address_2_cst': 'Address 2', 'address_3_cst': 'Address 3', 'city_cst': 'City', 'state_cst': 'State',
                      'zip_cst': 'Zip', 'country_cst': 'Country', 'salesrep_cst': 'Sales Rep', 'type_cst': 'Type',
                      'is_allowed_flat_cst': 'Allowed Flat?', 'iddef_cst': mark_safe('<p>Id'),
                      'date_created_cst': 'Created Date', 'date_suspended_cst': 'Suspended Date',
                      'date_first_tran_cst': 'First Tran Date', 'date_last_tran_cst': 'Last Tran Date',
                      'is_credit_hold_cst': 'Credit Hold?', 'old_balance_cst': 'Old Balance',
                      'balance_notify_cst': 'Balance Notify', 'balance_statement_cst': 'Balance Statement',
                      'balance_conversion_cst': 'Balance Conversion', 'balance_cst': 'Current Balance',
                      'receive_emails_cst': 'Receive Emails?', 'contact_domain_cst': mark_safe('<p>Contact Domain')}
```

views.py

```
def customer(request, id):
    if request.method == "GET":
        obj = AppCustomerCst.objects.get(id_cst=id)
        instance = get_object_or_404(AppCustomerCst, id_cst=id)
        form = CustomerMaintForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
        ContactFormSet = modelformset_factory(AppContactCnt, can_delete=True, fields=(
            'name_cnt', 'phone_cnt', 'email_cnt', 'note_cnt', 'receives_emails_cnt'))
        formset = ContactFormSet(queryset=AppContactCnt.objects.filter(idcst_cnt=id), prefix='contact')
        tpList = AppCustomerTpRel.objects.filter(idcst_rel=id).select_related('idcst_rel', 'idtrp_rel').values(
            'idtrp_rel__id_trp', 'idtrp_rel__tpid_trp', 'idtrp_rel__name_trp', 'sender_id_rel', 'category_rel',
            'cust_vendor_rel')
        TPFormSet = formset_factory(TPListForm, can_delete=True)
        tp_formset = TPFormSet(initial=tpList, prefix='tp')
        doc_list = DocData.objects.document_list(id)
        DocFormSet = formset_factory(DocumentListForm)
        DocFormSet = formset_factory(DocumentListForm)
        doc_formset = DocFormSet(initial=doc_list, prefix='doc')
        context = {'form': form, 'formset': formset, 'tp_formset': tp_formset, 'doc_formset': doc_formset, 'id': id}
        print(form.errors)
        return render(request, 'customer.html', context=context)

    elif '_edit' in request.POST:
        print(id, request.POST)
        cust_name = request.POST['name_cst']
        instance = get_object_or_404(AppCustomerCst, name_cst=cust_name)
        form = CustomerMaintForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/customers/customer/{id}")
        else:
            context = {'form': form, 'contact_form': contact_form}
            return redirect(request, 'customer.html', context=context)

    elif '_delete' in request.POST:
        cust_name = request.POST['name_cst']
        instance = get_object_or_404(AppCustomerCst, name_cst=cust_name)
        form = CustomerMaintForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            AppCustomerCst.objects.filter(id_cst=id).delete()
            return render(request, 'customers.html')

    else:
        pass
```

customer.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% url customer string %}
{% block content %}


<form method="post" action="/customer">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div style="height:300px;overflow:auto;">
        {{ form }}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="_edit">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="_delete">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 404 is because the form sends a `POST` to `/customer` and your URLs are

- `/customers/`
- `/customers/customer/<int:id>/`

So I'd first add a name to your `path` so it becomes something like `path("customers/customer/<int:id>/", views.customer, name='customer')`

Then change your form action to use django URL reversal;

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'customer' id=id %}">
```

By doing this it'll generate the URL for you based on the ID of the customer form you're on, assuming `id` is in the context which it appears to be from your view code.

That *should* solve the 404 and improve things a little.

Comment: When I update my form action as you suggested I'm now getting a new error: `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'customer' not found. 'customer' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @AlliDeacon Did you update the URL with the name `customer`? If you did, maybe your app is installed with an application namespace? In which case URL lookups become `{% url "myapp:customer" id=id %}`. Totally depends how you've setup your project & apps. Docs on this are here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls

Comment: it was the app namespace, but now running into another error, but at least a new error = progress!  Thanks a bunch for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll keep an eye out for a new question!!